# What is the Mean Squared Error for this estimator?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, unbiased-estimator, estimators, mse

I understand that to find the MSE, i must find the variance and bias and add them together. I've had trouble calculating either of these so a breakdown would be immensely helpful. The estimator is:
$$\hat{\mu}=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$

Comment: Just to make the question comprehensible.
$$ \hat{\mu} = (n-1)^{-1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}X_{i}$$

Comment: Thank You, may ask how'd you type it like that?

Comment: Sannin - see "LaTeX" under "[editing help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help)". To see how a particular expression or equation was generated, right click on it, `-> Show Math As -> TeX Commands`. You can copy and paste the code that gives between pairs of \$ symbols to reproduce them. For more information on what can be done, consult any of the myriad online guides for mathematics in LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the mean squared error is not the sum of the variance and bias, but the sum of the variance and the *square* of the bias; i.e., $$\operatorname{MSE}[w(\theta)] = \operatorname{Var}[w(\theta)] + \operatorname{E}[(w(\theta)-\theta)]^2$$ for some estimator $w(\theta)$ of the parameter $\theta$.

Second, the computation of this quantity for your estimator $\hat \mu$ would depend on whether the observations $X_i$ are independent.  If they are, then $$\operatorname{E}[\hat \mu] = \frac{n}{n-1} \mu,$$ assuming that $\operatorname{E}[X_i] = \mu$ (i.e., the parameter being estimated is the mean of the distribution).  Then it is easy to see that the square of the bias is simply $$(n-1)^{-2}.$$  The variance can be computed under the assumption of independence via the relationship $$\operatorname{Var}[X_1 + \cdots + X_n] = \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}[X_i].$$  The rest I leave to you.  However, without more information about how the $X_i$s are distributed, there isn't actually a whole lot more to do from a computational perspective.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to the website and forgot to mention some things. X1,....,Xn isan IID random sample of ovservation on the random VariableX. LEt mu=E(X) and variance= Var(X)